# Different between mvn clean, mvn install and mvn clean install

Tags: java, maven

I'm using Maven for my project. It is not an issue if my project doesn't use some local resources.
So that I'm following this guide
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61576687/6720896
to copy my local jar to local maven repository and validated by Maven.

As you can see, in the `maven-install-plugin`, I'm setting to install local repository at `clean` phase.
It means by `mvn clean`, maven will copy my jar to maven local repository.

The problem is, if I run `mvn clean` and `mvn install` by two commands separately => there is no problem
If i run `mvn clean install` => the build is failed as the log

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project xxxx:xxxx:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.xxxx:xxxx-ws:jar:1.0.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

Seem like by default, maven always execute following order: validate > compile > clean > install. I also tried  with 'mvn clean validate' but the error still occurs.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: What do you mean by `..copy my local jar to local maven repository and validated by maven`?

Comment: To directly answer your question title — `mvn clean install` simply means to run _clean_ and then run _install_. It _should_ give you the same result as if you ran `mvn clean` and then you separately ran `mvn install`. I think @Donat has it right that you are doing things in "clean" that you should not be doing. `clean` should _**not**_ "copy my jar to maven local repository"

Comment: @StephenP There is a subtle difference - see my answer.

Comment: @JFabianMeier - excellent point, and I overlooked that because that difference has never mattered to me in the ways I use maven, but the difference _is_ there.

Answer (score 5):

The question is not really clear, but my interpretation is as follows:

The OP wants to automatically add a dependency to the local repository by using `install:install-file`. Then the OP wants to use that dependency. This works if `mvn clean` and `mvn install` are run separately, but not if one runs `mvn clean install`.

The reason is as follows:

Maven resolves dependencies at the beginning of the process. So dependencies are already resolved before the `clean` of `mvn clean install` is executed.

This especially implies that you cannot install and resolve a dependency in the same Maven run.

If, though, you first run `mvn clean` (which installs the dependency) and then `mvn install` (which uses the dependency), everything is fine.

Comment: Yes, you're right and so sorry for making it very confusion. This is the issue that i got. By separating `mvn clean install` to two commands `mvn clean` and `mvn install` => it is solved.
But as you said, maven resolves dependencies at the beginning of the process, but for `mvn clean` it doesn't.

Comment: "mvn clean" installs the dependency? Does not it delete existing .class files and dependencies are resolved during "mvn install"?